# Google Maps API Marker Clusters Info window

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow, markerclusterer

How can I add an `info window` to the Google Maps `marker Cluster` listed below? The map is designed to cluster the markers zoomed out but I would like the markers when zoomed to the nearest extent to show an info window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
</meta>
 <style>
   #map_canvas {
    width: 1000px;
   height: 800px;
   background-color:#CCC;
   }
   #legend {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
 }
 #legend img {
vertical-align: middle;
}
 </style>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(-39.431441,-71.286622);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 2,
  center: pos,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
var c = ca[i];
while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}
function eraseCookie(name) {
createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
map.setCenter(pos);
 var all = [
[37.3952,-91.5482],
[37.212,-90.168],
[37.3331,-90.0782]
];
var gmarkers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
var lat = all[i][0];
var lng = all[i][1];
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: latLng,});
gmarkers.push(marker);
}
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);  
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>  
</head>
<body> 
  <div id="map" style="height:800px;width:1000px;"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how to add an infowindow to a marker.  Is that your question?  If so it is no different than how you do it without the clusterer. [MarkerClusterer example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_clustered.html).  What information do you want to put in the infowindow?

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample code for adding InfoWindow to markers in MarkerClusterer

Haven't noticed that in my code is jQuery needed so suppose we include these scripts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
</meta>
```

You might use following code.

Thanks to geocodezip.

```
var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 200,
    map: map

});
/*   <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64{binary data}" />   */


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

    var $infoWindowContent = $("YourText);
        info.setContent($infoWindowContent[0]);
        info.open(map, this);

});
```

As I see you have a for loop where store the text so I would recommend you add this into your `for loop`
Hope it helps a bit.

Comment: That looks like it might depend on JQuery.  Does it?

Comment: I used it in my c# project but it should work in this case either.

Comment: Does your C# project use JQuery?

Comment: Yes it does use jQuery.

Comment: The original question doesn't. You should include the dependency on JQuery in your answer or remove the dependency.

Comment: Can I get some more information on how to do it and where to add the script to the report above? Thanks

Comment: Using the data in the example